# Upper bounds on $f(x)=\frac{\cosh(a+x)}{\cosh(b+x)}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, hyperbolic-functions

What would be some good upper bounds on the following ratio
\begin{align}
f(x)=\frac{\cosh(a+x)}{\cosh(b+x)}
\end{align}
whre $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

I tried using $1+\frac{x^2}{2} \le\cosh(x)\le e^{x^2/2}$, but the bounds are not very good.

Also, from the plots that I did the function $f(x)$ seems to be bounded.
Thanks.

Comment: you can try to use the first derivative

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Can you please give a little more explanation as to how I should use the first derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{\cosh(a+x)}{\cosh(b+x)}\implies \log f(x)=\log \cosh(a+x) - \log \cosh(b+x) $$

$$\frac{d}{ds}\log \cosh s=\tanh s\implies \log f(x) =-\int_a^b \tanh(x+t)\,dt$$

Then, as $|\tanh(u)| \leqslant 1$ for all $u\in\mathbb{R}$, the triangle inequality for integrals gives immediately that

$$|\log f(x)| \le \left| \int_a^bdt\right|=|b-a|$$

which can be shown to be a sharp bound by looking at $x\to\pm\infty$. Thus:

$$|\log f(x)| \le |b-a| \implies f(x) \in [e^{-|b-a|},e^{|b-a|}] \,\, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Very Interesting approach. Thank you. Is there a tighter bound on $|tanh(u)| \le 1$, that would depend on $u$?

Comment: If you allow the bound to depend on $u$, the tightest bound you can get is just $|\tanh u| \le |\tanh u|$, which isn't much use. If you want a useful bound, you should generally look for the tightest bound within a *fixed family of functions* - I've taken that family to be the constant functions.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion as what family to use?

Comment: I don't understand your question - what purposes do you require such a bound for?

Answer (score 1):

Just from the definition of $\mathrm{cosh}(x)$ you can see that $$\frac{\mathrm{cosh}(a+x)}{\mathrm{cosh}(b+x)} = \frac{e^{a + x} + e^{-a -x}}{e^{b + x} + e^{-b -x}} = \frac{e^{a + 2x} + e^{-a}}{e^{b + 2x} + e^{-b}}$$
and so as $x \to \infty$ this will very quickly approach $e^{a - b}$, and as $x \to -\infty$ it will approach $e^{b - a}$. So all you have to worry about are the turning points in the middle, which you should be able to find and analyse using the first and second derivatives.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail about the approach with the derivatives?

Comment: the first derivative is given by $$f'(x)=\text{sech}(b+x) (\sinh (a+x)-\cosh (a+x) \tanh (b+x))$$ solve this and try to find the extreme points

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Once I find the extreme points what should I do next?

Comment: you must look for maxima or minima to find the bounds

Answer (score 1):

It is apparent that the answer will only depend on $\lvert b-a \rvert$, because the hyperbolic cosine is even and we can shift $x$. So let's work with
$$ f_c(x) = \frac{\cosh{(x-c)}}{\cosh{x}}. $$
Using the exponential expressions,
$$ f_c(x) = \frac{e^{x}e^{-c}+e^{-x}e^{c}}{e^x+e^{-x}} = \frac{e^{-c}e^{2x}+e^{c}}{e^{2x}+1} = e^{-c} + \frac{e^{c}-e^{-c}}{e^{2x}+1} = e^{-c} +\frac{2\sinh{c}}{e^{2x}+1}. $$
This expression is useful because it explicitly describes a function that is increasing or decreasing, depending on the sign of $c$: $e^{2x}$ is increasing, so $1/(e^{2x}+1)$ is decreasing. Hence the extrema occur as $x \to \pm \infty$.

- If $c>0$, the function is decreasing and so the maximum is $e^c$ and the minimum is $e^{-c}$.
- If $c<0$ the function is increasing, so the maximum is $e^{-c}$ and the minimum is $e^{c}$.

In both cases, the extrema are not achieved. Obviously if $c=0$ the function is constant. Hence we obtain
$$ e^{|c|} > f_c(x) > e^{-|c|}. $$

Comment: So, in your case $c=b-a$??

Comment: Yes, replacing $c$ by $b-a$ and $x$ by $x+b$ gives your function.

Comment: In the second case $c<0$, you have a typo, right?

Comment: Ah yes. I think it's right now.